# How does filterset particular rule in fortify SCA?

Tags: fortify, fortify-source

I want to move one rule to false positive using filterset or any other way. I don't want to move whole rule like following case. "Password Management: Hardcoded Password" one rule is there I want to move thread "private String Password;" line to false positive not an "Password="sample123""; This is real thread. I tried to AWB create filter but there is no one match like this type of logic. How to filter rule only particular criteria?

Answer (score 0):

When you mark some kind of issue as false positive, the AI engine can observe new ocurrences.